# Crashing on presenting IDMPhotoBrowser in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am integrating [IDMPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/ideaismobile/IDMPhotoBrowser) in my Swift Project.

I have created a bridging header and I have imported IDMPhotoBrowser.

`#import <IDMPhotoBrowser.h>`

In my view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, IDMPhotoBrowserDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 

    var photoBro = IDMPhotoBrowser(photos: imagesArray)
    photoBro.delegate = self
    presentViewController(photoBro, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

But when it is executed, I get the following error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString unloadUnderlyingImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165d6870'

In [IDMPhotoBrowser Library](https://github.com/ideaismobile/IDMPhotoBrowser), I found this function in `IDMPhoto.m`

```
// Release if we can get it again from path or url
- (void)unloadUnderlyingImage {
_loadingInProgress = NO;

if (self.underlyingImage && (_photoPath || _photoURL)) {
    self.underlyingImage = nil;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error it looks like it is expecting to do something to an array of IDMPhotos but instead has an array of strings...are you passing the right kind of array to the constructor?

Comment: That was so silly of me...I was not calling the right constructor.
Upvoted

Answer (score 1):

As @GoatInTHeMachine pointed, I was not passing the right kind of array.
But as I wanted to pass the imageURLs, I had to change the constructor.
The following worked for me:

```
var photoBro = IDMPhotoBrowser(photoURLs: imagesArray)
```